# IMDbPY - Licence for the texts

Tags: database, imdbpy

I don't find explicit information regarding the IMDbPY content. Is it copyrighted somehow? On IMDB site, I see that all the information is copyrighted, so I assume that this DB contents should also be.

Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the contents of each individual list file for the applicable copyright notice.

In *actors.list.gz* you can read the following:

```
Copyright 1990-2007 The Internet Movie Database, Inc.  All rights reserved. 

COPYING POLICY: Internet Movie Database (IMDb)
==============================================

This is a  database  of  movie  related  information  compiled  by
Internet  Movie  Database  Ltd (IMDb). While every effort has been
made to  ensure  the  accuracy  of  the  database  IMDb  gives  no
warranty  as  to  the accuracy of the information contained in the
database.  IMDb  reserves  the  right  to   withdraw   or   delete
information at any time. 

This service is provided for the information of users only. It  is
not   provided  with  the  intention  that  users  rely  upon  the
information for any purposes. Accordingly,  IMDb  shall  under  no
circumstances  be liable for any loss or damage, including but not
limited to loss of profits, goodwill or indirect or  consequential
loss   arising   out   of  any  use  of  or  inaccuracies  in  the
information. All warranties express or  implied  are  excluded  to
the fullest extent permissible by law. 

All information in this file  is  Copyright  2005  Internet  Movie
Database  Limited.  Reproduction,  distribution or transmission by
any means without the prior permission of IMDb is prohibited.  All
rights reserved. 

For further info visit http://www.imdb.com/licensing/contact

     -------------------------------------------------------

All data and software released by Internet Movie Database  Ltd  is
freely  available  to  anyone  within certain limitations. You are
encouraged to quote subsets of the database  in  USENET  articles,
movie  related  FAQs,  magazine  articles etc. We do ask, however,
that you make reference to the source of the data  and  provide  a
pointer to the database for the benefit of the reader. 

Permission is granted  by  the  copyright  holder  to  allow  free
distribution  of  this  file  and  any  other part of the Internet
Movie  Database  in  an  ELECTRONIC  FORM  ONLY,   providing   the
following conditions are met: 

     1. NO FEE OF ANY KIND, however indirect, will be  charged
        for  its  distribution.  If  this file is being stored
        for  later  distribution  to  anyone   that   can   be
        construed   as   a   customer   of  yourself  or  your
        organisation YOU MUST contact Internet Movie  Database
        Ltd for permission. 

     2. Each  of  the  database  files  may   be   distributed
        individually  but  only  in an unaltered form. All the
        header and trailer information, including this  notice
        and  the  details  on how to access the database, must
        remain intact. 

     3. Specifically the files may NOT be  used  to  construct
        any  kind  of  on-line database (except for individual
        personal use). Clearance for  ALL  such  on-line  data
        resources   must  be  requested  from  Internet  Movie
        Database Ltd 

     4. In addition, copies of  the  Internet  Movie  Database
        frequently  asked  questions  list and additions guide
        must be made available in the same area / by the  same
        method as the other database files. 

     5. CD-ROM  distribution  is  prohibited  without  written
        permission from the Internet Movie Database Ltd 

Distribution by e-mail, BBS and  Internet  systems  is  positively
encouraged within these limitations. 

The files and software which make up the  movie  database  may  be
uploaded  to  commercial  BBS  systems  providing  that  the above
conditions are met and no *additional* fees are applied above  the
standard connect time or downloading charges. 

For further info visit http://www.imdb.com/licensing/contact
```

Others such as *biographies.list.gz* don't have anything at the top.

http://www.imdb.com/interfaces shows the following:

> A subset of the IMDb plain text data files is available from our FTP sites. 
>   Please refer to the copyright/license information listed in
>   each file for instructions on allowed usage. The data is NOT FREE
>   although it may be used for free in specific circumstances.

Also check out the [Can I use IMDb data in my software?](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware) page.